# Edit Button on Each row to edit its row

Tags: vba, excel, button, edit

I am building an excel file.
I need multiple user to input data to his/her assigned columns for each row of data.
The first user creates the base columns of each row.
Then click on a button to create a button on each row for the second user to edit the row and add his/her data.

Thanks to this question/answer (@Tim Williams): [excel vba add form button to each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102089/excel-vba-add-form-button-to-each-row)
I was able to create button on each row.
But I want each button to be able to trigger a userform that would ask for the user input.
My question:
How to give each created button the ability to trigger the userform to edit that specific row?

Thanks for your help.

See pictures:
[image: excel]
[image: VBA]

Comment: This should be straight forward.  Name the form and each time a button is clicked yourformname.Show, you will then be in the form code and associated modules.  Now passing a variable to your form is interesting without making it public, such as the row number selected so the form processes on that data.  I suggest you read this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640155/vba-calling-a-private-function-inside-of-a-userform

Comment: Yes, I agree we are trying to achieve something similar. With your help I was able to figure it out!

Comment: Great news.  I once made an application with lots of buttons, one for each row with many rows.  Excel didn't like the overhead of that very much, you can almost use cell selection in the same manner (and toggle cell color on and off), not quite as intuitive but refreshing many objects on a page is something excel doesn't like much.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to my issue thanks to @Wookies-Will-Code

Each button is assigned an Onaction script which calls a module.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim btn As Button, t As Range, sht As Worksheet, i As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

sht.Buttons.Delete

For i = 5 To sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set t = sht.Cells(i, 4)
Set btn = sht.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With btn
  .OnAction = "Edit"
  .Caption = "Edit"
  .Name = "Editbutton_" & i

End With

Next i
End Sub
```

Then I created a module with this code, which is assigned to each button.

```
Sub Edit()
With UserForm1
    .Tag = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    .Show
End With
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Then on a simple userform with 3 text boxes, called Userform1 (TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3) I gave it this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    FillValues
End Sub

Private Sub FillValues()
With Me
    .TextBox1.Value = Cells(.Tag, 1).Value
    .TextBox2.Value = Cells(.Tag, 2).Value
    .TextBox3.Value = Cells(.Tag, 3).Value
End With
End Sub
```

The current result:
[image: 3]

Finally I added an OK button to the Userform1, with this code:

```
Private Sub OKCommandButton_Click()

With Me
Cells(.Tag, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(.Tag, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
Cells(.Tag, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
End With

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

The OK button just changes the row data with the data entered in the Userform.

Comment: Alright thanks, I went further into the issue today, yet was not able to get it working correctly.

Comment: I was able to find a solution thanks to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560187/populate-userform-with-records-from-current-row?rq=1